# How do I stop a jQuery long-polling request?

Tags: jquery, json, long-polling

I'm using...

```
   $.getJSON(url + "&callback=?", function (b) {
                .......
   });
```

for a long-polling request.  Sometimes it is necessary that I stop the current request being made.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

I think this works, but have never tried it for myself...

```
var theRequest = $.getJSON(url + "&callback=?", function (b) {
            .......
});

theRequest.abort();  // aborts the xmlhttprequest made
```

`$.getJSON()` should return the XMLHTTPRequest object, upon which you call the `abort()` method.

Comment: Thanks, this definitely looks promising...I'll try it out.

Comment: Just be careful that you don't call it again using "error" in the Json Request, otherwise abort will only stop it, only for it to restart itself. I.e --> abort is seen as an error.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're aborting because it's taking too long, but if so you can change your $.getJSON call to $.ajax and set a timeout:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'json',
  data: "param1=" + params,
  timeout: 7000,
  success: resultsHandler
})
```

Comment: It's not because it's taking too long, but good to know and thanks!